# Jest: how to test a function defined with "export function"?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function defined like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function TestFunc(props) {
  const [var1, setVar1] = useState(undefined);
  const functionA = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  };
};
```

Now I'd like to unit test `functionA`, I tried the following syntax but didn't work:

```
import * as TestFunc from './TestFunc';
describe('test test function', () => {
  test('function A', () => {
    expect(TestFunc.functionA(2, 3)).toBe(5);
  });
});
```

What is the correct syntax to make `TestFunc.functionA` work?

Answer (score 0):

`functionA` is currently private to `TestFunc`. Refactor your code so that you export `functionA` i.e.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const functionA = (a, b) => (a + b);

export function TestFunc(props) {
  const [var1, setVar1] = useState(undefined);
};
```

Once you have done this you will then be able to test `functionA` e.g.

```
import { functionA } from './TestFunc';
describe('test functionA', () => {
  test('that is behaves as expected', () => {
    expect(functionA(2, 3)).toBe(5);
  });
});
```

Comment: No, I won’t be able to refactor the code like this, I don’t own the code, I only test it.

Comment: Oh ok. In that case you are stuck as functionA is not actually invoked inside of TestFunc, it is just defined.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I need to discuss with the code author.

Comment: I had a look at the code again, `functionA` was actually defined as `const functionA = (props.a, props.b) => {return props.a + props.b}`. In this case I will not be able to refactor the code, right?

Comment: cant export two thing at same time, need to use {functionA ,TestFunc}

Answer (score 0):

try to `mount` that function adn then try to call function,

```
  it('function A', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<TestFunc />);
    expect(wrapper.find('functionA ')).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```